# New posts have wrong facebook like button code

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, nginx, facebook-like

I have a site where each new pictures uploaded has their **own view page** with a url like

```
http://mysite/pictures/view/27963. // App is made with Codeigniter over nginx
```

Since about one week ago **all new pictures** show a static number of likes:

[image]

If **I like** any of the new pictures **all are affected adding 1 like to them**

But the older shows their real number of likes. Ie, **this bug only affects pictures posted after a given date** (03/12/2013) .

Both views (old and new) has exactly the same code behind:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mysite/pictures/view/xxx" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

All meta tags are set:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxx" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Site" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite/pictures/view/27963" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite/documents/large/71b44e139f54400c2beaf459821dc1f3.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My description" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="yyy" />
```

Using http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug I have these Warnings:

> Meta with name instead of property: The meta tag on the page was
>   specified with name 'author', which matches a configured property of
>   this object type. It will be ignored unless specified with the meta
>   property attribute instead of the meta name attribute.
>
> og:image should be larger:larger: Provided og:image is not big enough.
>   Please use an image that's at least 200x200 and preferably 1500x1500.
>   (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Image 'http :
>   //mysite/documents/large/fbc7f9f7a63552a9ce3192c2cf720b73.jpg' will be
>   used instead.

The image referred by **og:image** exists and is reachable and is larger than 200x200.

**NOTE**: After pass failing pages through the FB debugger all they **start working well** and the second warninig "og:image should be larger:larger:" dissapears.

Any suggest is welcome...

Comment: Do you have a live demo of the site we can look at?

Comment: This was caused by a redirection issue. Is a very common problem. Thanks.-